# DNS server hosted in docker

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, docker

I am trying to follow [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syzwLwE3Xq4) on how to setup DNS server hosted as docker image.

But of course I am facing problems.

I have setup `named.conf` file as below. But i am completely uncertain what IP addresses I should put, I have put my local machine (that i use to run docker), default gateway ip:

```
acl internal {
  192.168.1.0/24;
  192.168.0.0/24;
  127.0.0.1;
  localhost;
  192.168.0.144;
};

options {
  forwarders {
    8.8.8.8;
    8.8.4.4;
  };
  allow-query { internal; };
};

zone "test.home." IN {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/test-home.zone";
};
```

Below i attach `test-home.zone` file

```
$TTL 2d

$ORIGIN test.home.

@           IN  SOA test.home. root.test.home. (
    202306151534    ; serial
    12h
    15m
    3w
    2h
    )

    IN  NS ns.test.home.

@           IN  NS  ns.test.home.

ns          IN  A   172.19.0.1

test-name   IN  A   192.168.0.144
```

Having such setup, I could resolve known names with commands:

```
nslookup google.com 172.19.0.1
```

The output of above command:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.19.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:401b:814::200e
          142.250.203.142
```

But when I tried to resolve my name, it could not find a domain:

```
nslookup test-name.test.home 172.19.0.1
```

and the output:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  172.19.0.1

*** UnKnown can't find test-name.test.home: Non-existent domain
```

## Other details:

###### I run my docker image on Ubuntu

###### I use Bind9 for DNS server.

###### Here is output of docker inspect command for container hosting DNS server:

```
 "NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "4b80c61e0f521afd51926708b1bfcc0fdb71a755566114af9cbe93cd0a44a462",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "53/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "53"
            }
        ],
        "53/udp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "53"
            }
        ],
        "953/tcp": null
    },
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/4b80c61e0f52",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "",
    "Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "",
    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Networks": {
        "dns-experiments_default": {
            "IPAMConfig": null,
            "Links": null,
            "Aliases": [
                "bind9",
                "ab0859f8c64b"
            ],
            "NetworkID": "9d5d03264503be5fee52e99bc04407da0d41f87eff3b07393805bc7aa019c734",
            "EndpointID": "e8612947adc69d959dbac41abf78f8f14b7394efb5bb11a4d453e8bea745c298",
            "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
            "DriverOpts": null
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is: it does not seem to resolve my name `test-name.test.home` correctly. Why and how could I fix it?

## Update

Per recommendation from comments, I tried using IP address from my docker inspect output, but it did not work either. When executing `nslookup` I get only:

```
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to UnKnown timed-out
```

Comment: Please  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers , allows others to use copy-and-paste and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Comment: The problem with https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyyjc.png  is that it appears that you query your gateway ( based on the docker inspect output `"Gateway": "172.19.0.1"`)  and that gateway is not your Bind name server, that  would be the  `"IPAddress": "172.19.0.2"` - only your own name server is aware of authoritative for your made-up domain

Comment: @HBruijn Hi and thanks for comments, unfortunately your suggestion does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite obvious after all.

I just have run

```
named-checkzone test.home test-home.zone
```

command and it turned out that it had two problems:

- serial number was out of range (specifying just, as example, 230616 worked)
- the file did not end in newline

After fixing it i run `named-checkzone` again and it returned OK and i could successfully resolve my DNS entries.